# Redirect Perl print statement to Apache log

Tags: perl, apache, logging, log4j, stdout

We have a Java web application running on Apache that calls Perl scripts in certain use cases. I would like to be able to redirect the print statements of the Perl scripts (which are printing to STDOUT by default) to the Apache log.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: STDERR maps to the apache error log by default, and there is an equivalent library for mod_perl.  Google "Perl Apache2::Log"

Comment: Thanks, but I don't follow. I was asking about redirecting STDOUT to the apache log.
For example, the Java code can be asked to execute a command like 
"perl myScript.pl", in which there will be calls like "print "Hello world"". I would like the Hello World to show up in the apache log.

Comment: You can redirect STDOUT to STDERR, then use @TerryE 's idea.

Comment: @David, thanks for that polite reminder to be polite to new-to-SO members.  I'm sitting in a Greek Tavern in the middle of the Aegean and had too many Ouzos.  Bizmark, this is standard Perl stuff and a simple Google Q will give you lots of examples of how to do this.  Sorry for being short. :-)

Comment: Assuming that shell command is executed using a `sh`-like shell, `perl myScript.pl >&2`. Actually, you don't even need to specify "`perl`" if the script is executable and has a valid shebang (`#!`) line.

Comment: @TerryE Wow - sounds exotic!  Definitely sounds a lot more interesting than what I'm doing.

Comment: Bizmark, I was just trying to say that this is just Perl 101 stuff, and I'd just apologised, so I am not sure why the flame :-(

Comment: @TerryE, sorry as well if I sounded too harsh. I just sensed a little uh...condescension...in your original reply when I didn't infer what you were getting at. I know it's 101, that's why I'm here, and I do appreciate the help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using this in the Perl scripts worked:

```
print STDERR "my comment";
```